# SSH connections within LAN slow down/freeze

Tags: networking, router, ssh, lan

When SSHing (and this would presumably be the case with other protocols) to devices within my LAN using `192.168` addresses, such as a Raspberry Pi or server, everything works fine for some time, but after I leave it inactive for maybe ten minutes, it freezes up. If I try typing, sometimes it'll go through after a delay and start working again, but other times it'll just stay frozen.

I figured this was just a case of my AT&T router being garbage, or my Raspberry Pi having weird networking issues, but I've confirmed that [it happens to other people to](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62771934#62771934), and that it's not just my Raspberry Pi (if I SSH to a definitely-working rack server I've got hooked up directly to my router with ethernet, the same thing happens).

If I instead connect through my static IP address, as if I wasn't at home (I've got port 22 forwarded to the same server), everything works fine. I can leave the connection for hours, come back, and instantly start typing again at full speed.

Thus, it seems like my router's doing some sort of weird deprioritization of LAN traffic. I'd really like to know if this is normal, and if there's a well-known cause of this or way to fix it (I can `rsync` files about thirty times faster using the `192.168` address, but don't typically do it since I'm worried about it freezing up).

Answer (score 0):

If the router is deprioritizing inactive LAN traffic, you can adjust the [keepalive interval](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3026/164143):

```
Host 192.168.*
    ServerAliveInterval 60
```

If you have this in your client `ssh_config`, a null packet will be sent to the server by the client when connected to 192.168.0.0/16 if no data has been sent for 60 seconds. The server, if it is up, will reply to the keepalive. This should trick your router into prioritizing the connection. Because the null packet is sent *within* the SSH tunnel, the router will be unable to distinguish between it and interactive input.